# How to center a text? - Pixlr

Tags: pixlr

Every time I select text, the bottom has more space than the top. So whenever I try to place it in the center of an image for example, it's always higher and never centered.

[image: 1]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I don't think pixlr has that functionality, at least I couldn't find any. It doesn't have custom guides either, which would have been ideal for centring something. Maybe draw something like a square, move it to the centre, then you can move the letter to centre it on the square, then delete the square. [see example](https://imgur.com/u9JOVAP)

Comment: Thanks, it works but still the alignment may not be perfect. I found a workaround, wrote it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround:

1. Write the text
2. Click on "page" then on "finishing" (translated from Italian so the names could be different)
3. Merge Layers
4. Copy Layer (CTRL+C) (COMMAND+C)
5. Go Back (CTRL+Z) (COMMAND+Z)
6. Paste (CTRL+V) (COMMAND+V)